# Recreate materialized view with grant

Tags: oracle, sql-grant, materialized-views

I have a materialized view that I want to modify it's query.

Since you can't execute `create or replace on` for materialized view,

and you must drop it before and then create it again,

what is the best way to do that with no losing the grants on the MV?

I'm using Oracle 11g.

Thanks.

Comment: You should have a script which executes the grants in your source control repository. If you don't have that, then write the script before you drop the MV.

Comment: Yes.. I just want to know if there is better way...also I tried to use dbms_metadata.get_ddl to generate the object ddl with the grants, but no success